# Changing TextView text using setText with Volley Response

Tags: android, android-volley, settext

I am working on a project which needs to change its textview's text, once the fragment is created. The values will be from my database. I'm able to get the values but I can't pass it to my TextViews. What method should I use? I tried `setText()` inside the try-catch but it didn't work. I'm terribly sorry. I'm just a newbie.

```
public class MostlyBorrowedBookLayout extends Fragment {
private Button popup;
private PopupWindow popupWindow;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
View myView;
SessionManager session;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.botd_layout, container, false);
    popup = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnpopup);
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    final TextView txtTitle= (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    final TextView txtAuthor= (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtAuthor);
    final TextView txtPublisher= (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtPublisher);
    final TextView txtRate = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtRate);
    final TextView txtAvailability = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtAvailability);
    final TextView txtBookLevel = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtBookLexile);

    //ERROR HOW CAN I CALL THE VALUE FROM onResponse
    txtTitle.setText(bookTitle);
    txtAuthor.setText(bookAuthor);
    txtBookLevel.setText(bookLevel);
    txtPublisher.setText(bookPublisher);
    txtAvailability.setText(availability_name);
    // convertToString
    HashMap<String, Integer> user_int = session.getUserLexileNID();
    Integer lexile = user_int.get(SessionManager.KEY_LEXILE);


    //final TextView
    final TextView testing = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.txtBookLexile);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.relative);
    final int userLexile = Integer.parseInt(lexile.toString());
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    String bookTitle = jsonResponse.getString("BookTitle");
                    String bookAuthor = jsonResponse.getString("BookAuthor");
                    String bookPublisher = jsonResponse.getString("BookPublisher");
                    int bookLevel = jsonResponse.getInt("bookLevel");
                    int availability_name = jsonResponse.getInt("availability_name");

                    //tried having the setText here but wont work


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Mostly Borrowed Book Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    MostlyBorrowedBookRequest mostlyBorrowedBookRequest = new MostlyBorrowedBookRequest(userLexile,responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    queue.add(mostlyBorrowedBookRequest);
    popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          PopUpCommentRate dialog = new PopUpCommentRate();
          dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "my_dialog");
        }
    });
    return myView;
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried to debug?? Is onResponse() method getting called??

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh No sir how do i do debugging sir?

Comment: put a break point inside onResponse() and start your app with "Debug app" instead of "Run app". Refer https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Ill try sir thanks for your guidance ill reply later for my laptop lags a lot with android studio ill just add a question sir would setText work in the try catch?

Comment: yes, if code is executed.

Comment: what error did u get while setting up text to textview?

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh thanks sir ill be replying later doing what you suggested Im current in the middle of building my app and I cant cancel it as I once cancel a build and it destroyed my project. I'll be doing your recommendation afterwards thank you ^^

Comment: @Manish I think the my code in onresponse is the one that has the error

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh sir I did an alteration with one of my project and yes it does alter textview using setText in try catch what might be the error in my code?

Comment: i recommend that first use Log to check bookTitle,bookAuthor,bookPublisher and.. have some value.